# some assumption on integrability to deduce uniform integrability

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose µ is a finite measure, $f_n \to f $
a.e., each $f_n$
is integrable, f
is integrable, and $\int |f_n−f|\to 0$
. prove $f_n$
is uniformly integrable. here is my try:
we can use [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1331955/if-mu-is-finite-then-f-n-is-uniformly-integrable-iff-sup-n-intf-n?rq=1) equivalence

we can easily see :
$|\int |f_n| - \int |f|| \le \int|f_n - f| < \epsilon$
$\:$ by essumption. 
so $\int |f_n| \to \int |f|$ and $\int |f| $ is bounded so is $\int |f_n|$
taking supremum we can deduce the $sup_{n \to \infty}\int |f_n|$ is bounded.
and we know that for $m(E)<\delta$ we have for integrable functions on that we have $\int_E |f| < \epsilon$ and the proof is completed.
is this right?

Comment: @5xum is it ok now?

Comment: Yes it's okay now. I mean the question and not your proof

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly , showing $sup_{n \to \infty}\int |f_n|<\infty$ is one step of the proof. Then you have to show that for each $\epsilon>0$ , you can find a $\delta>0$ such that $m(A)<\delta$ implies $\sup_{n}\int_{A}|f_{n}|<\epsilon$ . This cannot be just done by saying that this is true for $f$ and hence true for $f_{n}$ . This step requires a proper justification and is the main step of the proof.

Here's how I would argue(I'll be very verbose and explain everything in detail):-

First show that a finite collection of integrable functions $\{f_{1},...,f_{n}\}$ is uniformly integrable. That is for each $f_{k}$ you'll find $M_{k}$ such that $\int_{|f_{k}|>M_{k}}|f_{k}|<\epsilon$ . So simply take $M=\max(M_{1},...,M_{k})$ to show that $\sup_{k}\int_{|f_{k}|>M}|f_{k}|<\epsilon$ is uniformly integrable .

Next also see that if $\{f_{n}\}$ and $\{g_{n}\}$ are two uniformly integrable families then $\{f_{n}+g_{n}\}$ is also uniformly integrable. That is by triangle inequality $\sup_{n}\int|f_{n}+g_{n}|<\infty$ and given any $\epsilon$ you can find a $\delta_{1}$ and $\delta_{2}$ such that $m(A)<\delta_{1}\implies \sup_{n}\int_{A}|f_{n}|<\epsilon$ and $m(A)<\delta_{2}$ implies $\sup_{n}\int_{A}|g_{n}|<\epsilon$

Thus take $\delta=\min(\delta_{1},\delta_{2})$ to get for all $m(A)<\delta$ ,  $\sup_{n}\int_{A}|f_{n}+g_{n}|\leq \sup_{n}\int_{A}|f_{n}|+\sup_{n}\int_{A}|g_{n}|<2\epsilon$

Now let $f_{n}\xrightarrow{L^{1}} f$ . Then given $\epsilon>0$, you can find $N$ depending on $\epsilon$  such that $\int|f_{n}-f|<\epsilon\,,\forall n\geq N$ . So now , using the results I proved above, find $M$ depending on $N$ and $\epsilon$ (and hence only on $\epsilon$) such that $\sup_{k=1,...,N}\int_{|f_{k}-f|>M}|f_{k}-f|<\epsilon$ . (This can be done as we have only $N$ (finitely) many functions) .

And hence you have:-

$$\int_{|f_{n}-f|>M}|f_{n}-f|<\epsilon$$ for $n\leq N$

And also $$\int_{|f_{n}-f|>M}|f_{n}-f|\leq \int|f_{n}-f|<\epsilon$$ for all $n\geq N$

Thus $$\sup_{n}\int_{|f_{n}-f|>M}|f_{n}-f|<\epsilon$$

Hence $\{f_{n}-f\}$ is an uniformly integrable family. Also $\{f\}$ is uniformly integrable as it's only one function.

Thus $\{f_{n}-f+f\}_{n}=\{f_{n}\}_{n}$ is an uniformly integrable family.

This is the complete rigorous justification. Obviously you can omit proofs of results that you know the proof of if I have used them.

Comment: wow! thank you so much @Mr.GandalfSauron

Comment: @hr1380 Consider marking as answer. That is important as it removes the question from the unanswered section